# Почему люди "шатаются"?

Tags: этимология

"Шататься" — это синоним слова "качаться". Но почему те, кто бесцельно бродят где-то, тоже "шатаются"? Даже медведи, которые не впали в спячку, называются шатуны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение "бесцельно ходить" действительно построено на аналогии с шатанием. Но думаю, это связано не с тем, что "тело" шатающегося качается из стороны в строну, а с тем, что оно ходит туда-сюда, что и порождает ассоциацию с шатанием. Стоять (соблюдать вертикальную составляющую) при этом он может вполне себе прямо, прочно и вертикально.
Аналогично - про деталь и медведя.

//---------------

Добавлено после "принятия" ответа.
Мне самому эта версия не кажется абсолютной. Но по логике именно так будет много точнее сведения к шатаниям пьяного и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Охотники отметили что зимой не спящий в берлоге медведь чаще  пошатывается при ходьбе то ли от голода то ли  от болезни он и более аггрессивный в это время .